# Pipe bash commands

Tags: bash

I'm trying to download a `tar.gz` package with `wget`, decompress it and rename the decompressed directory all in one (piped) command.

My attemps were:

```
wget -O- $URL | tar fvxz - -C $DEST

wget -O- $URL | tar fvxz - | mv - $DEST
```

What am I failing at?

Comment: [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tar.html) is clear that the file operand doesn't need to immediately follow the `f`, but there are *many* broken implementations where it does. Perhaps OP has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have BSD or GNU tar, you can do this:

```
mkdir -p "$DEST" && wget -O- "$URL" | tar --strip-components 1 -xvzf- -C "$DEST"
```

Since GNU tar has `--strip-components`, but that's not a standard solution. Anyway, you can't really do this with a single pipeline since you have to have the directory already, and there are perfectly good ways of doing this if you're willing to give up on the whole single pipeline anyway.

```
mkdir -p "$DEST" &&
cd "$DEST" &&
wget -O- "$URL" | tar -xvzf-
cd * && # Assumes the result only has one directory
mv * .. # Assumes no dotfiles
```

You can resolve issues of dotfiles and tars of multiple directories by tweaking this answer, if necessary.

Comment: Use of the `z` flag already implies a non-ancient, more-than-POSIX-minimum tar.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley the use of the `z` flag doesn't seem sufficient to imply the existence of `--strip-components`.